# AZCopy - MD5 calculated and MD5 in property always miss matching?

Tags: azure, azcopy

Why Azcopy MD5 in property and MD5 calculated always miss matching - is there any specific reason for it? or any thing that we need to take care if that needs to be matched.

Azcopy Code as below :

In below  MD5 calculated: OxsjX5iE8FnUyV7pnq6fOQ== is not matching with MD5 in property: J/nQ76JOLDu+0M/E8buGZQ== -->

```
AzCopy /Z:FilePath /Source:"Source" /Dest:"C:\LocalFolder" /sourcesas:"SOURCE SAS" /Pattern:VHDName.vhd /CheckMD5
[2017/09/28 00:44:15][ERROR] http://.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/VHDName.vhd: The MD5 hash calculated from the downloaded data does not match the
MD5 hash stored in the property of source: http://softnasimages.blob.core.window
s.net/vhds/VHDName.vhd. Please refer to help or documentation for detail.
MD5 calculated: **OxsjX5iE8FnUyV7pnq6fOQ==**
MD5 in property: **J/nQ76JOLDu+0M/E8buGZQ==**
Finished 0 of total 1 file(s).
[2017/09/28 00:44:15] Transfer summary:
-----------------
Total files transferred: 1
Transfer successfully:   0
Transfer skipped:        0
Transfer failed:         1
Elapsed time:            00.00:06:02
```